# TYPO3 enable rte custom content element

Tags: typo3-8.x

how do I enable the Rich Text Editor for a custom content element in TYPO3 8.7?

I tried

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myCustomElement'] = array('showitem' => '--palette--;
LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.general;
general,header,subheader,header_link,bodytext,
richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css],rte_enabled;
image,--div--;
LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.appearance,--palette--;
LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.frames;
frames,--div--;
LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,--palette--;
LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;
visibility,--palette--;
LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;
access,--div--;
LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories, tx_gridelements_container, tx_gridelements_columns');
```

and

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myCustomElement']['columnsOverrides']['bodytext']['defaultExtras'] = 'richtext[*]:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]';
```

in TCA/Overrides in my Extension. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have improve your code and its work properly now

```
    $myfield=[
'showitem' => '
--palette--; LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.general; general,header,subheader,header_link,bodytext,image,
--div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.appearance,
--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.frames;frames,
--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,
--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,
--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
--div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories, tx_gridelements_container, tx_gridelements_columns
',
'columnsOverrides' => [
  'bodytext' => [
     'config' => [
        'enableRichtext' => true,
        'richtextConfiguration' => 'default'
     ]
  ]
]
];
```

And

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myCustomElement']=$myfield;
```

May It will help you!!

Comment: Thank you! This also answerd another question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55376681/dedicated-rte-config-per-ctype

Answer (score 0):

The RTE in TYPO3 comes from an TYPO3-System-Extension called **rte_ckeditor**. Somehow I managed to de**activate** it. After reactivating it I used the following in my TCA:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myCustomElement'] = array('showitem' =>'--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.general;general,header,subheader,header_link,bodytext,image,--div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.appearance,--palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.frames;frames,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.visibility;visibility,--palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,--div--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_category.tabs.category, categories, tx_gridelements_container, tx_gridelements_columns');
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['myCustomElement']['columnsOverrides']['bodytext']['defaultExtras'] = 'richtext[*]:rte_transform[mode=ts_css]';
```